# RtMidiIn not finding Ports in Release version c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I can't find a related solution so i finally post here.
I have a very small program that uses the RTMidi library to map the controllers keys as hotkeys. Everything works fine in debug mode and releasing the app doesn't give me any errors either, but the RTMidiIn class isn't finding any Ports in the release version.

This is my code

```
MidiToMacro::MidiToMacro(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_ui.setupUi(this); 
    RtMidiIn *midiin;
    try 
    {
        midiin = new RtMidiIn(RtMidi::WINDOWS_MM);
    }
catch (RtMidiError &error) {
    m_ui.uiLog->append("midiin initiation failed!");
    error.printMessage();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

unsigned int nPorts = midiin->getPortCount();
QString inputCount = QString::number(nPorts);
m_ui.uiLog->append("There are " + inputCount + " MIDI input sources 
available.");
std::string portName;
std::string akai = "Akai MPK49 2";
opened = 1000;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nPorts;++i) 
{
    try 
    {
        portName = midiin->getPortName(i);
        if (portName == akai)
        {
            midiin->openPort(i);
            midiin->setCallback(&mycallback, this);
            opened = i;
        }
    }

    catch (RtMidiError &error)
    {
        //not printing an error
        error.printMessage();
        delete midiin;
    }

    QString portnumber = QString::number(i);
    m_ui.uiLog->append("  Input Port #" + portnumber + ": " + QString::fromStdString(portName));
}

if (opened == 1000) 
{
    m_ui.uiLog->append("Error finding Akai Controller!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to define WINDOWS_MM in the preprocessor definitions of release.